# How to get a notification when MacBook battery needs to charge?

Tags: macos, battery, notifications

I get no notifications whatsoever regarding the battery levels before my MacBooks die. What setting do I need to enable in System Settings to get a notification when a MacBook battery needs to charge?

I’ve already looked in the battery menubar widget, and in System Settings under battery and under notifications.

This regards a 2022 MacBook Pro and a 2018 MacBook Air, each running the latest macOS (13.4.1).

Comment: Not sure there is a system preference setting for this, but did you look at Shortcuts?

Comment: @nohillside I think if you enable "Battery" in the menu bar, you will receive a notification when your battery is low and needs charging.

Comment: Might be useful to know which Mac and what OS.

Comment: Also, do you not get low battery warning at 10%?

Comment: What are Shortcuts? @nohillside

Comment: @benwiggy I get no battery notifications before my MacBooks die.

Comment: What models of Mac are they? Might the batteries be old and failing, i.e. suddenly cutting out, rather than reaching 0% gracefully? have you modified anything? If all else fails, you could install Coconut Battery, which is a third-party battery utility

Comment: @2540625 See /System/Applications/Shortcuts.app and the related online documentation on support.apple.com

Comment: A 2018 MacBook is pushing 5 years and the average life expectancy of a battery is 3 to 5 years.  The 2022 model is obviously well short of that.  While the older one is likely to have bad cell(s) it’s not so for the newer one; but it’s not unheard of either.  The critical question still hasn’t been answered though:   ***Are they just shutting off with no warning without even going to sleep?***

Comment: First sentence of my post answers your question: yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize *when* you get notified of a low battery condition (i.e. percentage or remaining time), you’ll need something like [Coconut Battery Plus](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/).

[image]

There is a free version of Coconut Battery, but it lacks the notification support.  If you want this feature, you’ll need to purchase the “Plus” version for ~$15 USD (prices on website are in Swiss Francs - CHF)

Comment: I am not asking how to customize when I get a notification that my battery needs to be charged, I am asking how to get any notification before my MacBook dies of uncharged battery.

Comment: You’re supposed to get a notification at 10%.  If it’s just turning off (not even going to sleep), then you have a very different problem.  See my comment in benwiggy’s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some version of macOS have options to allow Notifications for Energy Saver  in System Settings.

[image]

However, I don't have this in Ventura, but I do get low battery notification at 10%.

Comment: My OS is newer than this screenshot. I get no battery notifs before my Books die.

Comment: The concerning part of this comment thread is that you get no notifications at all before it dies.  What vintage are these MacBooks?  I think it best that we rule out a problem with battery having bad cell(s).

Comment: I’ve added now to the original question the years my MacBooks were made.